# How to apply margin to a div on condition using styled component and react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i want to apply margin based on the prop for the styled component using react and typescript.

below is my code,

```
function Parent() {
    return (
        <Child margin='variant'/>
    );
}

interface Props {
    margin?: any;
}

function Child({margin}: Props) {
    return (
        <Wrapper margin={margin}/>
    );
}

const Wrapper = div<{margin: any;}>`
   margin: 0 4px; //usually a margin of 0 4px should be used. if this child is called from parent 
   //component then it should use 0 4px 4px 8px;

`;
```

This child component is used in two components one in Parent and other in Subcomponent.

when this child component is called from Parent component it should use margin of 0 4px 4px 8px and if not should use margin of 0 4px.

how can i modify the above code. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [pass props](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props)

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  margin: ${(props) => props.margin || "0 4px"};
`;

// margin: 0 4px 4px 8px;
<Wrapper margin="0 4px 4px 8px">test</Wrapper>

// margin: 0 4px;
<Wrapper>test</Wrapper>
```